# website for mobile and desktop

Tags: web, mobile-website

I'm going to build a website which contains a chain of questions asking the user a question and the next question depends on the previous answer by using JSP, my problem is that I want the user to access this website on both computer and mobile device, please can anyone help me how to build the website which can be opened on both computer and mobile device without changing the appearance.

many thanks for any answer,

Answer (score 0):

You may consider to use the [HTML5 Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/) for that, regardless which server side scripting language you use.

Answer (score 0):

There are many libraries (or check the user agent manually) to detect if a user is using a mobile browser or not, this would tell your script which layout to use, mobile or desktop.

There are some frameworks designed for creating mobile websites, two notable ones are [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/) and [Sencha Touch](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch).

Sencha touch is more complicated in my opinion, but it has a smoother UI while jQuery Mobile is just like good ol' jQuery but it's still in it's beta stages and has some UI bugs.

Comment: thank you very much for all your answers, please can you clarify how to check when the user used mobile or desktop browser. I have to use two different design one for mobile and another for desktop or one website with some specific changes ?? many thanks